# Plot time of audio in x-axis instead of the audio sampling rate in tkinter GUI display of matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4CZv.jpg)I am a beginner in Tkinter GUI and I am learning about wave audio display with the corresponding time of audio. I want to display the audio time in x-axis of matplotlib graph.
I tried the axis.set_xticks() and function but not work in my case. 
It would be helpful if anyone could solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your MCVE, but have a look at the [`matplotlib.ticker` class](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html). Once you have calculated the time vector by

```
times = numpy.linspace(0, (self.audio.signal.shape[0]) / fs, num=(self.audio.fs))
```

(which you did correctly as far as I can see), you can e.g. use `MultipleLocator()` to set the ticks. Note, that `times` has to be in units of seconds.

```
import time
# Set major ticks every 60 seconds
self.ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(60))
# Set minor ticks every 10 seconds
self.ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
# Define format of xtick labels with help of `time` module as Minutes:Seconds
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda s, x: time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(s)))
self.ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

This should lead to something looking like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you gehbiszumeis for your suggestions but it does not work in my case. The error is a mismatch of ticks and sample length. RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 24257 ticks from -66180.0 to 1389180.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS

Comment: The error you get means that for some reason the axis object is trying to produce too many ticks for labeling, namely exactly `len(range(-66180, 1389180, 60)) + 1 = 24257` ticks. This would mean that your audio file is 24257 seconds long (i.e. 6.7 hours). Is this the case? If yes, you can increase the argument of `MultipleLocator` to e.g. `3600` to have major ticks at each hour. If not, the time vector you use for plotting is not in units of seconds.